# Can you say "economic agnostic"?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases

Can you say "economic agnostic" like in the following sentence?

> Strategy cannot be economic agnostic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No; *agnostic* there is an adjective and must be modified by an adverb, so you must say "economical**ly** agnostic".

But when you employ *agnostic* as a noun, the adjectival modifier is correct.

> Prof. Sartorius is an economic agnostic; his proposal does not depend on either a Keynesian or a supply-side interpretation.